# Converting Laravel-4 Eloquent query results to arrays

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to get my route to insert a new row into the database, and if successful return the record (with its new primary key id) in some JSON. I'm getting the following error:

```
{
    "error":
    {
        "type":"BadMethodCallException",
        "message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::to_array()",
        "file":"\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php",
        "line":1418
    }

}
```

This is my route:

```
Route::post('/client/create', function()
{
    $client = Client::create(Input::all());
    if($client)
    {
        return json_encode(array('Result' => 'OK', 'Record' => $client->to_array()));
    }
    else
    {
        return json_encode(array('Result' => 'ERROR', 'Message' => 'Error Inserting Record =('));
    }
});
```

According to the Laravel docs I've read, you're supposed to use `->to_array()` to convert your model to an array, and `::create` returns an instance of the model if successfully inserted. I've checked the database, and the records are being inserted just fine.

Comment: try ```return $client->toArray();``` and you can also use ```return $client->toJson();```, if is that what you need.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro Thanks, that works! Its not passing in the id of the inserted row, but I can always get that elsewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default if you were to return an Eloquent model directly it would convert the model to it's JSON representation. This is because the `__toString` magic method on each model returns the model as JSON by using the `toJson` method.

As such the model implements both the `ArrayableInterface` and `JsonableInterface`. That means you can directly call `toJson` or `toArray` on a model.

Now you can mark columns as hidden. This means that when a model is converted into it's array or JSON representation some columns are removed (think publicly accessible API, you don't want passwords showing up!). I'm not totally sure but maybe the ID of your model is being hidden.

At the end of the day, all you need to do is return the instance.

```
return $client;
```

It'll be converted to JSON for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks! Seems I was mistakenly using the Laravel 3 docs. The id issue turns out to have been caused by some database triggers, once I removed them I got the id out as well.

Comment: Thanks! I was sure, it must exist something, because Laravel is GREAT!

Answer (score 3):

The `to_array()` method comes from Laravel 3. Use `toArray()` in Laravel 4.

Answer (score 1):

I see question similar you try to return data to jquery jtable and same me

```
Player::orderBy($sort)->paginate($pagesize)->getCollection();
return Response::view(array('Result'=>'OK','Records'=>$player->toArray()));
```

for try many hour I found solution getcollection  pull instance from object and then solve